# How to solve restricted_client error in google sign in flutter IOS?

Tags: flutter, google-signin, flutter-dependencies, google-console-developer

I'm trying to implement google signin in my flutter app when I click google-signin button. [image]

when I click continue  it redirects to a browser window and tells

[image]

I have enabled google sign in and place json file in correct path 
[image: firebase console]

can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on 'Learn More' in the error message above should take you to the Google Cloud Console configuration for your project, where you need to configure the OAuth consent screen information before you can use Google Sign In.

If you already know your Google Cloud project information, visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent will take you to the consent screen configuration.

You can find more information at https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158849?hl=en.